# Calculate a integral of : $I = \int \int_{V} y^{-2} d \lambda_2(x,y)$ where: $V = \{ x^2 + y^2 > 1, |x| < \frac{1}{2}, y > 0 \}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, fubini-tonelli-theorems

Calculate a integral of :

$$I =  \int \int_{V} y^{-2} d \lambda_2(x,y)$$

where: $V = \{ x^2 + y^2 > 1, |x| < \frac{1}{2}, y > 0 \}$

---

Using help provided by @geetha290krm I was able to write the solution.

[image]

From the drawing I see that it would be appropriate to integrate $ \frac{1}{y^2}$ over $y \in (\sqrt{1 - x^2}, \infty)$ and then over $x \in (0, \frac{1}{2})$. The function that we will integrate is continous on the area of interest so we can use Fubini's theorem - therefore we have that:

$$\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}} \int_{\sqrt{1-x^2}}^{\infty} \frac{1}{y^{2}} dx \ dy = \int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}} \left[ - \frac{1}{y} \right]^{\infty}_{\sqrt{1-x^2}} dy = \int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} dx = \left[ arcsin(x) \right]^{\frac{1}{2}}_0 = arcsin \left( \frac{1}{2} \right) = \frac{\pi}{6}$$

Is that correct?

Comment: There are no points in the region with $y$ close to $0$. You cannot integrate w.r.t. $y$ from $0$ to $\infty$. You forgot the condition $y >\sqrt {1-x^{2}}>\frac {\sqrt 3} 2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The integral over $A$ is $\int_0^{1/2} \int_{\sqrt {1-x^{2}}}^{\infty} \frac  1{y^{2}}dydx=\int_0^{1/2}\frac 1 {\sqrt {1-x^{2}}}dx$. Use the fact that $\arcsin x$ is an anti-derivative of $\frac 1 {\sqrt {1-x^{2}}}$

Remark: **The limits of integration are constants only for rectangular regions**.

Comment: I edited the original question. Thank you for help!

Comment: is that correct now? @geetha290krm

Comment: Yes, it is correct. @thefool